# DistributionNotFound error even though package is installed

Tags: python, pip

I am getting  pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: nose>=1.3.4
error, but i get version 1.3.7 by running the command

```
pip show nose
```

Trace :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/bin/qweez", line 5, in
>
> from pkg_resources import load_entry_point   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2655, in
>   
>       working_set.require(**requires**)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 648, in
>   require
>       needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 546, in
>   resolve
>       raise DistributionNotFound(req) pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: nose>=1.3.4